# Change table owner w/ CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

Does CockroachDB let me change the table owner? I can’t find something that’s equivalent to Postgres’ `REASSIGN OWNED` command. I ultimately want to control which user has access to modify the table.

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB doesn't have the same notion of “table owners” that Postgres does. All tables are “owned” by `root` by default, but you can control access that other users have through `GRANT`.

First you’ll need to create a new user:

```
cockroach user set johndoe;
```

Now, log in to the Cockroach SQL shell and grant `johndoe` the permissions you want (you can find a list of permissions [in the documentation](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/grant.html#supported-privileges):

```
cockroach sql
GRANT ALL ON db TO johndoe;
```

After that you can quit the SQL shell (`ctrl + C`) and then access the shell again as the new user:

```
cockroach sql --user=johndoe
```

Answer (score 0):

change the owner of a table with

```
ALTER TABLE <name> OWNER TO <newowner>
```

see https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/owner-to.html